# AndroidManifest.xml how do you specifically exclude devices WITH a feature?

Tags: android, xml

I have 2 APKs, one for normal devices and one for Android wear. In the wear xml I have this line:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" android:required="true" />
```

which works ok. However in the non-wear devices I want to filter out all wear devices in the XML. Is that possible ?

Comment: Google play will take care of it AFAIK but you can check if particular feature is available or not using packagemamager in the code

Comment: I was under the impression that [the Wear APK was packaged inside the non-Wear APK](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html), not uploaded to the Play Store directly. By definition, since Wear devices do not access the Play Store directly, everything accessing the Play Store is non-Wear.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot, this clears it for me.